# Procedural assignment to a non-register shiftedy is not permitted, left-hand side should be reg/integer/time/genvar -- this is the error I am getting

Tags: verilog, alu

I have almost solved this question and made changes in the code as shown below. I am also not getting any error but the only thing is that the output of 'shiftedy' is not as expected. Also, I use Xilinx to run my projects and I am getting red line across the simulation output for 'shiftedy'. below is the screenshot for the same. If someone could help me with that.

```
module shifter(shiftedy, x, constamt, constvar, y);
output [31:0] shiftedy;
input [4:0] x, constamt, constvar;
input [31:0] y;
wire [4:0] amount, m, n;
wire shiftdir;

assign m = constamt & constvar; 
assign n = x && constvar;
assign amount = m || n;

assign shiftedy = (shiftdir == 1'b1) ? (shiftedy <= y << amount) : (shiftedy <= y >> amount);
endmodule

module stimulus;
wire [31:0] shiftedy;
reg [4:0] x, constamt, constvar;
reg [31:0] y;

shifter s1(shiftedy, x, constamt, constvar, y);
initial
begin
$monitor($time, "X=%b, constamt=%b, Y=%b, shiftedy=%b", x, constamt, y, shiftedy);
end

initial
begin
x=5'd0; y=32'd0; constamt=5'd0; constvar=5'd0;
#5 x = 5'd3; y = 5'd4;
#5 x = 5'd5; y = 5'd2; constamt = 1'b1;
#5 x = 5'd5; y = 5'd10;
#5 x = 5'd2; y = 5'd10; constamt = 1'b0;  
#5 x = 5'd10; y = 5'd5; constamt = 1'b1;
end
endmodule
```

[image: ALU]

[image]

Comment: Added the error

Comment: Nope it didn't: It gave me below mentioned error:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not assigning the shiftdir so it is becoming x or z.There are some basic syntax issues too in your code.

```
module shifter(
   output [31:0]   shifted_y
  ,input  [4:0]    x, const_amt, const_var
  ,input  [31:0]   y
  ,input           shift_dir
);
wire [4:0] amount, m, n;

assign m = const_amt & const_var; 
assign n = x && const_var;
assign amount = m || n;

assign shifted_y = (shift_dir == 1'b1) ? y << amount : y >> amount ;

endmodule

module stimulus;
 wire [31:0] shiftedy;
 reg  [4:0]  x, constamt, constvar;
 reg  [31:0] y;
 reg         shift_dir;

shifter s1(shiftedy, x, constamt, constvar, y,shift_dir);

initial begin
$monitor($time, "X=%b, constamt=%b, Y=%b, shiftedy=%b", x, constamt, y, shiftedy);
end

 initial begin
      x         = 5'd0 ;
      y         = 32'd0;
      constamt  = 5'd0 ;
      constvar  = 5'd0 ;
      shift_dir = 1'b0;

    #5 x = 5'd3 ; y = 32'd4 ;
    #5 x = 5'd5 ; y = 32'd2 ; constamt = 5'b1;
    #5 x = 5'd5 ; y = 32'd10;
    #5 x = 5'd2 ; y = 32'd10; constamt = 5'b0;  
    #5 x = 5'd10; y = 32'd5 ; constamt = 5'b1;
 end
endmodule
```

based on the diagram you can use the below code too for the design logic even though not completely correct you can modify it .

```
module ALU (
    output [31:0] s
   ,input  [31:0] x,y
   ,input  [04:0] const_amount
   ,input         shift_dir,add_sub,const_var
   ,input  [1:0]  function_class,logic_function
);

// shifter logic
  wire [4:0]  amount    = const_var ? x [4:0]     : const_amount;
  wire [31:0] shifted_y = shift_dir ? y << amount : y >> amount ;

// ALU
  wire [31:0] k       = {32{add_sub}} ^ y ;
  wire [31:0] alu_out = add_sub ? x + k : x - k;

//logic unit
  wire [31:0] logic_out = (logic_function == 2'b00 ) ?  x  & y :             // ADD
                          (logic_function == 2'b01 ) ?  x  | y :             // OR
                          (logic_function == 2'b10 ) ?  x  ^ y :             // XOR
                          (logic_function == 2'b11 ) ?  x ~| y : 32'b0 ;     // NOR

// output mux
  assign s =  (function_class == 2'b00 ) ?  shifted_y :
              (function_class == 2'b01 ) ?  alu_out   :
              (function_class == 2'b10 ) ?  alu_out   :
              (function_class == 2'b11 ) ?  logic_out : 32'b0;

endmodule
```